# How do you use pac4j for OAUTH2 in a multi-tenant environment?

Tags: java, tomcat, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pac4j

I would like to use [pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j) in a Java application to create a Tomcat filter or Tomcat valve.  The filter or valve must support OpenID Connect using standard OAUTH2 authorization code flows.  Even better would be to build on top of [j2e-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j) to do this, but I cannot use the OAUTH2 filter in j2e-pac4j.  My filter or valve needs to modify the request object by adding an HTTP header.  The web app behind the filter/valve requires the HTTP header, and it's third party so I can't change this.

I will use Open ID Connect so I can get the JWT, but other than using the JWT and its contents and perhaps the userinfo endpoint of Open ID Connect, I am simply doing a standard OAUTH2 flow.  Here's the complication:  The server I will redirect to for authorization supports multiple tenants.  This means that the URL I redirect to will have the tenant name in the URL.  This means that instead of a URL like

```
https://authorization.server.com/oauth/authorize
```

(Note, leaving off `?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=myclientname&state=nonce&redirect_uri=...` for the sake of clarity.)  I will be required to redirect to a URL like one of:

```
https://authorization.server.com/tenantname/oauth/authorize
https://authorization.server.com/oauth/tenantname/authorize
https://authorization.server.com/oauth/authorize?realm=tenantname
```

How do you do this with pac4j, or better yet, j2e-pac4j?  I've been told that pac4j will not support this, where every client potentially uses a different redirect URL for authorization.